# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

After installing Entity Framework 6.0.1, I keep getting an error

`MAXModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.` (see Figure below)

[image]

Before I installed it, it was fine.

I'm using MVC 4.

Thank you.
robotron

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The current version of the `Oracle Managed ODP` is not compatible with `EF 6`, learned this the hard way. Use `EF 5` instead.

There is a ticket open at oracle support, I can't find it right now though.

**EDIT**

I got another upvote on this today, so I thought I'd add that the newest version of `ODP.net` now supports `EF 6`.

**EDIT AGAIN**

Since a while back an [official ODP.NET entity framework package is available at nuget (link)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)

Comment: That's what I did after posting the problem, used EF 5. Forgot to post the solution. After using EF5, everything worked. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Works with EF 6, after installing the ODP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ODAC 12c Release 3 which includes support for Entity Framework 6 Code First and Code First Migrations; NuGet, .NET Framework 4.5.2; and ODP.NET, Managed Driver XML DB. As per

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html