# No Entity Framework Provider for ADO.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client Without Config

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, arcgis, odp.net

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run this query:

```
var query = from u in StageEntity.STAGINGINTERACTIONPOINTS
  where u.OBJECTID == OBJECT_ID
  select u;

"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nStagingDB.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: 
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider
with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'. 
Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' 
section of the application config file. 
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."
```

However, the issue I believe is that I'm unable to access a config file in runtime. This is because my application is an ArcObjects Extension and for some reason ignores all Config files that are not Config.esriaddinx. Therefore at run time, I get the connection string from the config file.

This works fine for SQL servers, but I have not tried this in Oracle before. I was wondering if there is something I need to include and declare at runtime for Oracle ODP to work.

Here's the connection string that I pull and call:

```
connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=examplehost.com)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = sid)));PASSWORD=hunter2;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=poor_username&quot;"
```

I then call this connection string whenever I declare an entity which I did making a [partial class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861570/entities-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments)

I have also looked at [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143889/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name) that had a similar issue, but I'm running the latest ODP.net (v 6.121) with Entity 6 which should be compatible.

Also, the following fix:

```
public partial class StagingEntities : DbContext
{
    private volatile Type _dependency;

    public StagingEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        _dependency = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);

    }
}
```

does not work.

Comment: Where did you get ODP.NET from? How did you install it? If using Nuget, make sure to get the one labelled "Official". There are two downloads, one for ODP.NET and one for the ODP.NET EF libraries. Get both of them.

Comment: Yes nuget and I do have both packages:
Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver and 
Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework Driver and entity was also installed using nuget

Comment: The scripts included with the Nuget package are supposed to automatically update your app.config or web.config to register our EF provider. Is that happening?

Comment: Unfortunately the type of application I'm working with does not include config files. So if I want to include an entity in SQL for example, I would have to parse the config at runtime to build the connection string. But yes the config files are generated, but the ArcMap extension application type does not include the config files at run time which is the issue.

Comment: Josh, you can put the entries manually in the machine.config instead if you use nuget. Or you can get the XCOPY Installer version and choose to do a "machine wide configuration": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

Answer (score 6):

**Your solution:**
Please reinstall NuGet package for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client-https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/

**Extra information:**
I had the exact same issue, but for Oracle.DataAccess.Client. My issue said: "*No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.*".

I had recently migrated from EF5 to EF6. The old version of *Oracle Managed ODP* is not compatible with EF6. After installing *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework*, I had to replace all occurrences of *Oracle.DataAccess.Client* in my project to *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client*. It worked fine.

Comment: I had an issue using EF with an asp.net core application that is referencing a class library that handles the EF work( i.e has the context...).
Once I added the entityFramework section into my app.config in the asp.net project, It worked.

Comment: I had the same issue and installing the packages to my webservice project helped

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem couple of weeks back. I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and ODP latest. I am using the entity framework in console library(.dll) and calling it from a WCF Service.

The solution that worked for me was I have to install the nuget package for the entity framework and ODP provider in the WCF service too, as it refers for the ODP configuration only from the WCF web config. (Weird, but I have to do that).

Also read somewhere that we have to do this only for console library projects.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: That is correct. To be more "cloud friendly" we no longer register the EF provider in machine config.

Comment: My above comment applies to Nuget. If you use XCOPY or OUI installers, you can do a "machine wide installation" and it will still update the machine.config.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was copying the App.config from my .NET Framework EF project into my .NET Core MVC project.