# How to Add/Activate "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" in the EF 6 provider config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am learning to make ASP.Net MVC Web application using VS2013 following [these video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrr66APUwBk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=8). When I got the following error:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'. Make sure the
>   provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the
>   application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

(In the video, the database provider used is the natural `System.Data.SqlClient` for ASP.Net application, but I need to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`)

The error itself is [not new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143889/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name) in SO. And, as suggested by the error message and by the accepted answer of the SO question, I checked if the ODP.Net provider is supported by EF 6.0 and I found that [it is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730568). Nevertheless I still cannot make it work.

I am pretty new to MVC and so I seek your understanding if there be any concepts of MVC application/settings which I understand wrongly at this point and I am open to your corrections.

Some additional info which might be useful:

- I use ASP.Net Web Application template provided by my VS2013 to start
  the project. I use MVC template for it and only "Add folders and core
  references for" MVC. I neither "Add unit tests" not "Host in the cloud"
- In the template, there isn't `app.config` file, but there is `Web.config` file (does this make any difference? It is suggested in the error message to "Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the
  application config file".)
- In the Web.config file, I found the following `entityFramework` portion:

```xml
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

- I notice that there is

  ```xml
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />`
  ```

  line there. And thus I try to similarly add:

  ```xml
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type=???, EntityFramework.???" />
  ```

  But I do not know what to write for the `type` attribute and the `EntityFramework.???` and has been stuck for a couple of hours. And if I do not put it, I got the following warning:

  > The required attribute "type" is missing

  Any help for this will be appreciated.

I also am open if you know that there is any additional things which I need to do besides adding the provider to fix this issue. My connections strings in the `web.config` file are as follow:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcWebApplication1-20160212010850.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcWebApplication1-20160212010850;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data source=aaaaa;user id=bbbbbb;password=cccccc;persist security info=True"   providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [an Oracle's ODP.Net document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt) and [an Oracle Community forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2619480?start=0&tstart=0):

Apperantly, according to the accepted answer, until early 2014, the EF 6 is not supported by ODAC as stated in its [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149). One must partially use EF 5 to work with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`

When I checked the document that the accepted answer refers to, however, I did not find the statement which suggested what the answerer wrote - leading me to believe that as of now, `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` could have been supported in EF 6.

And then I found [this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt) which contains quite a number of tricks to solve possible issues when using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` in EF 6.

The one which particularly works for me is by adding:

1. Config Sections

```xml
    <configSections>
      <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>
```

2. Dependent Assembly

   ```xml
   <dependentAssembly>
     <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
     <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```

   (I used `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` version 4.121.2.0)
3. Entity Framework provider

   ```xml
   <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
   ```

All in the `Web.config` file